# Can I render an N2 CMS page as part of another normal MVC Razor view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, n2cms

I have a few how-to pages that exist in the N2 CMS system and I want to include one or two of them at the bottom of a normal MVC view. I have manged to use the N2 APIs to pull back a ContentItem for the specific page in the Controller using:

```
ContentItem contentItem = global::N2.Context.Current.UrlParser.Parse("/support/sample-code/example-one");
```

Now I was hoping it was as simple as pulling this content item back and then asking N2 to render the related page/parts in place in the view but I haven't been able to find ANY docs or info on if this is possible or how I would go about it.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution to my issue.

It pretty much **IS** as simple(ish) as just telling N2 CMS to render the ContentItem as you can use `Html.DroppableZone()` by passing it the ContentPage... ish...

`Html.DroppableZone()` can accept a `ContentItem` and a "ZoneName" (`string`) and it will render the specified ZoneName as if it was on the page the is contained in the `ContentItem`. This does mean you're not rendering the page BUT a `Part` from the page BUT in our case that's fine as all of the pages we want to render actually contain a part called "ServiceTemplate" which contains all the info we want to render on the other pages.

*(Although you could possibly work out a way to use the original page's View to get the layout of the parts if you wanted the full page... Good luck as I had a go at it and found lots of issues with `@section main{...}` etc...)*

### Controller

So as that's all fairly confusing so here is our Controller:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using N2;

namespace Data8.Website.N2.Controllers
{
    public class ServiceDocsController : Controller
    {
        // GET: ServiceDocs
        // Returns the specified service doc (partial view for AJAX)
        public ActionResult Index(string url)
        {
            // Get the Content Item for that N2 Page (if it is an N2 Page!)
            ContentItem contentItem = Context.Current.UrlParser.Parse(url);

            // Ensure we found a valid N2 Content Page that contains a Service Template as one of it's parts... (these are all we will render!)
            if (contentItem == null || !contentItem.IsPage || contentItem.Children.All(ci => ci.TemplateKey != "ServiceTemplate"))
            {
                return new HttpNotFoundResult("Page doesn't exist or doesn't contain a Service Template Part!");
            }

            // Return the partial view of that contentItem
            return PartialView(contentItem);
        }
    }
}
```

It:

- Takes the URL of the page you want
- Uses the `N2` `UrlParser` to find the `ContentItem` for that page
- Check's it's the type of page we want (**WE** are only after pages with a `ServiceTemplate` part on it)
- Then passes that `ContentItem` to the Index view

***FYI: We will be using AJAX to draw this on demand so it only returns a partial... You could use `return View(contentItem);` instead to draw a full page with Layouts etc...***

### View

Now in the View:

@   @using N2
    @model ContentItem

```
@foreach (ContentItem contentItem in Model.Children)
{
    if (contentItem.Visible && contentItem.ZoneName != null && !contentItem.IsPage && contentItem.TemplateKey == "ServiceTemplate")
    {
        @Html.DroppableZone(Model, contentItem.ZoneName).Render()
    }

}
```

The view loops though the ContentItem's Children and for each child it finds that matches the `ServiceTemplate` Part we are looking for it renders it using the `Html.DroppableZone()` function passing it the full page's ContentItem and the ContentItem's `ZoneName` for this `ServiceTemplate`.

SO as I said "***SIMPLE!***" ;)